# Fire ionicModal on ionicPopup close

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to open ionic modal whenever the user presses the **Yes** button, but close ionic popup whenever the user presses the **No** button. How can I do this?

At the moment, ionic popup opens up in each case. Here is my code so far:

**services.js**

```
 function PopupService($ionicPopup) {

   function acceptAppointmentPopup(scope) {
     return $ionicPopup.show({
       title: 'Are you sure you want to accept this appointment?',
       scope: scope,
       buttons: [{
         text: '<b>Yes</b>',
         type: 'button-positive',
         onTap: function(e) {}
       }, {
         text: 'No',
         onTap: function(e) {}
       }, ]
     })
   }

   return {
     acceptAppointmentPopup: acceptAppointmentPopup
   };
 }
```

**controller.js**

```
function BusinessPendingAcceptanceCtrl($scope, PopupService, ModalService) {

  $scope.newMessageModal = function() {
    ModalService.show('templates/modals/new-message.html', 'ConsumerNotificationsCtrl as vm');
  }

  $scope.showAcceptAppointmentPopup = function() {
    $scope.data = {}
    var myPopup = PopupService.acceptAppointmentPopup($scope);
    myPopup.then(function(res) {
      $scope.newMessageModal();
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: You are using the service incorrectly, a service should not have any user interface interaction from a design perspective. This is a big code smell and illustrates poor understanding of how angularjs structure should be. The best place to handle the popups would be in the controller as that has a relationship with the view.

Comment: I was following the instructions here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionicpopup-inside-a-factory/11787/4. Is it better as a factory?

Comment: @methuselah Why would you need a `factory` or a `service` in this case? The `$ionicPopup` and `$ionicModal` are already simple to use, why wrap them up in a service? If you want to reuse your modal and popup I suggest you set them to `$rootScope` which will be shared across your application.

Comment: No. Think of service, as a singleton class, that holds data that is common to controllers. Think of a *M*odel holder, the *V*iew is the html side, the *C*ontroller is where it is responsible for the updating the view and uses the service to pull in the data. *Following the instructions* is a dead giveaway in lack of understanding.

Comment: Also, as of late, the OP has been posting ionic-centric questions lately, using SO as a crutch to complete the task without understanding, is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Here is another link I have been following: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-modal-service-with-extras/15357. I thought it seemed practical, because using $ionicModal and $ionicPopup across multiple seemed to create a lot of code bloat.

Comment: Another SO question on the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214451/ionic-modal-windows-from-service/. Is everyone following this approach doing it wrong? If so, why hasn't it been addressed in each instance by the individuals replying?

Comment: @t0mm13b True, true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ionicPopup` supports `confirm` *(a YES, NO dialog)* which returns a `promise` and as an argument passes the result. You can use it like this:

```
$ionicPopup.confirm({ // example taken from official documentation
  title: 'Consume Ice Cream',
  template: 'Are you sure you want to eat this ice cream?'
}).then(function (result) {
  if (result) {
    // At this point user confirmed that they want to eat the ice cream,
    // so lets open a modal to visually show the user how the ice cream is being consumed
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal = modal;
      $scope.modal.show();
      // This is where the user starts drooling :P
    });
  } else {
    // This user apparently hates ice cream, which is ridiculous...
  }
});
```

You can get more info on the [official documentation page](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/).

---

**Integrating my example into your code:**

**services.js**

```
function PopupService($ionicPopup) {
    function acceptAppointmentPopup(scope) {
        return $ionicPopup.show({
            title: 'Are you sure you want to accept this appointment?',
            scope: scope,
            buttons: [{
                text: '<b>Yes</b>',
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function(e) {
                    return true;
                }
            }, {
                text: 'No',
                onTap: function(e) {
                    return false;
                }
            }]
        })
    }

    return {
        acceptAppointmentPopup: acceptAppointmentPopup
    };
}
```

**controller.js**

```
function BusinessPendingAcceptanceCtrl($scope, PopupService, ModalService) {

    $scope.newMessageModal = function() {
        ModalService.show('templates/modals/new-message.html', 'ConsumerNotificationsCtrl as vm');
    }

    $scope.showAcceptAppointmentPopup = function() {
        $scope.data = {}
        var myPopup = PopupService.acceptAppointmentPopup($scope);
        myPopup.then(function(res) {
            if (res) { // Here we check if user pressed Yes - Yes button returns true
                $scope.newMessageModal();
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  As you've seen I have set up `$ionicPopup` as a service which I call from the controller. How would I integrate your code into mine?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a whirl!